# Pourquoi le nom d'Amérique a-t-il changé depuis le XVIIIe siècle?

Tags: orthographe, histoire

J'ai trouvé [un scan d'un traité de 1794 en français et anglais](https://archive.org/details/treatyofamitycom00grea/page/2/mode/2up), et ledit traité utilise le nom « Amerque » plutôt que « Amérique »  Pourquoi aujourd'hui disons-nous « Amérique »?

Comment: Si tu continues à lire le document, tu verras *L'Amérique* plusieurs fois.  Peux-tu faire une comparaison, combien de cas d'*Amérque* ?  Une fois, c'est probablement une coquille.

Answer (score 4):

Comme le dit [@livresque](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46847/pourquoi-le-nom-dam%C3%A9rique-a-chang%C3%A9-depuis-le-xviiie-si%C3%A9cle#comment93700_46847), en allant sur [les pages suivantes](https://archive.org/details/treatyofamitycom00grea/page/6/mode/2up) on voit qu'il s'agit d'une coquille sur la première page de titre en français, coquille donc probablement due au processus d'impression et non aux rédacteurs du document. Le nom « Amérique » est apparu bien avant le 18<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Le continent que l'on connait en Français sous le nom d'Amérique été nommé ainsi en mémoire du navigateur [Amerigo Vespucci](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerigo_Vespucci) qui l'a décrit en 1503 (dans *[Mundus Novus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerigo_Vespucci#Mundus_Novus)*).

*America* a été [employé pour la première fois en 1507](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Waldseem%C3%BCller#Invention_de_l%27%C2%AB_Am%C3%A9rique_%C2%BB) par le géographe [Martin Waldseemüller](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Waldseem%C3%BCller) dans un ouvrage écrit en latin.

**Le terme a été francisé** pour la première fois en **1558** par [André Thévet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Thevet) dans *[Les singularités de la France antarctique, autrement nommee Amerique, & de plusieurs terres et isles decouvertes de nostre temps](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k109516t/f1.item)*.